# "File not found" error with PyCharm in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

I am migrating from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, and I am migrating from Wing IDE to PyCharm.  I'm very familiar with Linux, and Linux file paths, as I have used it in the cloud for several years, but I'm new to desktop.

My problem is this:  in the terminal, I can navigate to ~/Software_Projects/NT_Test_Projects/Px_Lib, but with the following Python lines in PyCharm I get "FileNotFound" error.

```
dest = r"~/Software_Projects/NT_Test_Projects/" + py_input_file[1:-3]

dir_files = os.listdir(dest)
```

Those lines produce the same file path as I see in the terminal -- ~/Software_Projects/NT_Test_Projects/Px_Lib -- so I don't know why I am getting this error.

I have tried numerous permutations (I even left off the leading ~) but I keep getting the same error.

I'm using PyCharm 2021.3.2 (Community Edition) on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question turns out to be:

"/home/myxtc/Software_Projects/NT_Test_Projects/" + py_input_file[1:-3]

You can see the full project path in "Run - Edit Configurations."  PyCharm needs the full path, not the familiar ~ to specify the home directory.